# Is it grammatically correct to say, "I wish there were fewer mosquitoes here."?

Tags: sentence-construction

What about, "I will take **fewer** subjects this semester." ?
I believe that the usage of 'fewer' is right here as I read that (on the web) fewer is usually used when referring to things in the plural. But, I just want to reconfirm.

Comment: Your dictionary is correct when it defines the adjective fewer as "of a smaller number."

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic so that we can clarify the question before people start trying to answer it. I think there is an interesting question here, but we need to understand a bit more. Would you explain why all of the sudden you're not sure of something you think is correct? Do you have an example of fewer being used with a singular subject that caused you to have some doubts?

Comment: @ColleenV I wanted to reconfirm because when I used fewer in the above sentences,  a friend of mine told me that it was grammatically incorrect. No other reason.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:
Yes, It's right.

Long answer:

You use *fewer* and *less* in different ways.

You can use **fewer** when you're referring to people or things in the plural (when it's countable).

> There were fewer people in the room.
>
> There are fewer days in one week
>
> I've fewer cats.

Instead, you can use **less** when you're referring to something you can't count and doesn't have plural (when it's uncountable).

> There's less coffee.
>
> There was less information in the database.
>
> There was less salt.

**Remember: Every uncountable noun is singular.**

There a lot of articles about *less vs fewer*. If you want to deepen this argument or you have some doubt, check out these articles:

[Less  or fewer](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/less-or-fewer)

[Using less and fewer](http://www.studyenglishtoday.net/english-grammar-using-less-and-fewer.html)

[Difference between less and fewer](http://www.learnenglish.de/mistakes/fewvsless.html)

[Use less or fewer (other tips)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/less-or-fewer)

Comment: _Fewer_ is **not** a synonym of _less._

Comment: @P.E.Dant I wrote a mistakes, I checked it.

Comment: In English, we don't capitalize the first word after a comma or any other punctuation except the _period (full stop)_ and (sometimes) the _colon._

Comment: Oh, We don't too.

Comment: Ebbene...ma avete capitalizzato "We" dopo la virgola! Inglese è esattamente come Italiano.